# Android NDK: Hardware float point for ARMv6

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I know android provides support for `ARMv5TE` and `ARMv7a` CPU. (`armeabi` and `areabi-v7a` folders)
Most Android Phones's CPUs now are `ARMv6` without `VFP`, `ARMv6` with `VFP` and `ARMv7` with `VFP`.

My app has physics simulation and I wish to target devices with hardware float point only. (`VFP`). I do not wish to support devices without `VFP`.

How do I configure NDK project to compile `ARMEABI` code to be `ARMv6` with `VFP` instead of `ARVv5TE` ?

I can block old `ARMv6` without `VFP` and `ARmv5` device via Google Play interface when APK is uploaded.

Comment: how do you do to block old ARMv6 without VFP and ARMv5 via Google Play? (excluding one by one because of the processor model?)

Comment: We don't. You can block per device if you like but there is no such devices. HTC Hero what else ? HTC Here has no OpenGL ES 2.0 We use OpenGL ES 2.0 So it is blocked by OpenGL ES 2.0 already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDK does not really provides any convenient way to change default build options. You can only add additional flags but not override standard options.

Default `LOCAL_CFLAGS` and most of other options will not work for you because NDK puts its options after yours and overrides your flags. The only solution I know is to define global `APP_CFLAGS` in the `Application.mk`. So the following should result in binaries optimized for armv6 having VFPv2:

```
APP_CFALGS += -march=armv6 -mno-soft-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp
```

Also if I remember correctly, vfp instructions on armv6 hardware require to compile your code in arm mode (not thumb). Specify `LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm` for every target in `Android.mk` to achieve this.

By the way I think that you will not be satisfied by performance of armv6 device. Even newest hi-end armv7 processors are about 10 times slower than modern Intel Core CPUs.

Comment: Can you provide some reports on Intel vs ARM performance debate?

Comment: ARMv7 is not 10 times slower then Intel Core 2. ARM float point in software runs 10+ slower then ARM with VFP.